# pandas: new column; if columns A, B, C are equal to 0, column is equal to 0. Else 1

Tags: python, pandas

I have a multiindex pandas dataframe, which I have sliced down to the following:

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
slice = data.loc[:, idx[1, ['Gx', 'Gy', 'Gz'], 'value']]
```

```
           1            
          Gx    Gy    Gz
       value value value
0        -26    37   -72
1        -28    37   -72
2        -27    37   -71
3        -28    37   -75
4        -27    38   -75
5        -29    40   -75
6        -30    39   -78
...
```

I need to get another column, which is 0 if Gx, Gy, Gz all equal 0, and otherwise equals 1.

I would like this to be vectorized, so I am trying to avoid using apply, though it seems like this is impossible to do in a vectorized fashion because two series cannot be compared on equality.

`result = slice.loc[:, idx[i, 'Gx', 'value']] == slice.loc[:, idx[i, 'Gy', 'value']] == slice.loc[:, idx[i, 'Gz', 'value']] == 0`

Fails, because `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

This seems like something that ought to be easily vectorizable, but all examples I can find of something similar use `apply()`.

I know that `np.where()` can be used with something like this, but from my understanding this is impossible. Because `slice` is multiindexed, np.where() cannot consume it, because I need to use `.loc` rather than normal bracket slicing.

Comment: Please give a [mcve] so that we can test the impossibility of `np.where`

Comment: Don't name things `slice`, it overrides a builtin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `0` is Falsey, you can use `any`

```
slice_.any(1).astype(int)
```

Comment: This is the best answer, it's incredibly fast (~.01 seconds on 250,000 rows).

Answer (score 2):

Hint from `nunique`

```
slice.nunique(1).ne(1).astype(int)
Out[846]: 
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    1
5    1
6    1
dtype: int32
```

Updated

```
slice.abs().sum(1).ne(0)
```

Comment: I really like your solution. However, your solution will return `0` when 3 columns having same non-zero values such as `45,  45,  45` while OP wants `1`. Does I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

Using [`pd.Dataframe.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) and [.all](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html)

```
df.eq(df.iloc[:, 0], axis=0).all(1)
```